# Odd C# behavior

Tags: c#

I'm a hobby programmer.
I tried to [ask this question earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37061253/c-sharp-equal-seems-to-be-incorrect?noredirect=1#comment61670459_37061253) on a very unstructured way (Sorry again), now I try to ask on the proper way.
I wrote the following code that seems to work unreliably.
The code was written like this for several reasons. I know it's messy but it should still work. To explain why I wrote it like this would mean that I need to  explain several weeks' of work that is quite extensive. Please accept that this is at least the least worse option I could figure out. In the below sample I removed all sections of the code that are not needed to reproduce the error.
What this program does in a nutshell:
The purpose is to check a large number of parameter combinations for a program that receives streaming data. I simulate the original process to test parameter combinations.
First data is read from files that represents recorded streaming data.
Then the data is aggregated.
Then I build a list of parameters to test for.
Finally I run the code for each parameter combination in parallel.

Inside the parallel part I calculate a financial indicator called the bollinger bands. This is a moving average with adding +/- standard deviation. This means the upper line and the lower line should only be equal when variable bBandDelta = 0. However sometimes it happens that CandleList[slot, w][ctr].bollingerUp is equal to CandleList[slot, w][ctr].bollingerDown even when bBandDelta is not 0.
As a result I don't understand how can line 277 kick in. It seems that sometimes the program fails to write to the CandleList[slot, w][ctr]. However this should not be possible because (1) I lock the list and (2) I use ConcurrentBag. Could I have some help please?

[Source files are here.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vjekslhsysqaebc/test.zip?dl=0)

The code is:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;

namespace Justfortest
{
    class tick : IComparable<tick>  //Data element to represent a tick
    {
        public string disp_name; //ticker ID
        public DateTime? trd_date; //trade date
        public TimeSpan? trdtim_1; //trade time
        public decimal trdprc_1; //price
        public int? trdvol_1; //tick volume

        public int CompareTo(tick other)
        {
            if (this.trdprc_1 == other.trdprc_1)
            {
                return other.trdprc_1.CompareTo(this.trdprc_1); //Return the later item

            }
            return this.trdprc_1.CompareTo(other.trdprc_1); //Return the earlier item
        }
    }

    class candle : IComparable<candle>  //Data element to represent a candle and all chart data calculated on candle level
    {
        public int id = 0;
        public DateTime? openDate;
        public TimeSpan? openTime;
        public DateTime? closeDate;
        public TimeSpan? closeTime;
        public decimal open = 0;
        public decimal high = 0;
        public decimal low = 0;
        public decimal close = 0;
        public int? volume = 0;
        public decimal totalPrice = 0;
        public decimal bollingerUp = 0;  //Bollinger upper line
        public decimal bollingerDown = 0;  //Bollinger below line

        public int CompareTo(candle other)
        {
            if (totalPrice == other.totalPrice)
            {
                return other.totalPrice.CompareTo(totalPrice); //Return the later item
            }
            return totalPrice.CompareTo(other.totalPrice); //Return the earlier item
        }
    }

    class param : IComparable<param>  //Data element represent a trade event signal
    {
        public int par1;
        public int bollPar;
        public int par2;
        public int par3;
        public int par4;
        public int par5;
        public int par6;
        public decimal par7;
        public decimal par8;
        public decimal par9;
        public decimal par10;

        int IComparable<param>.CompareTo(param other)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
    class programCLass
    {
        void myProgram()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello");
            Console.WindowWidth = 180;
            string[] sources = new string[]
            {
                @"C:\test\source\sourceW1.csv",
                @"C:\test\source\sourceW2.csv",
            };
            List<candle>[] sourceCandleList = new List<candle>[sources.Count()];
            List<param> paramList = new List<param>(10000000);
            var csvAnalyzer = new StringBuilder();

            {
                List<tick>[] updatelist = new List<tick>[sources.Count()];
                Console.WriteLine("START LOAD");
                for (var i = 0; i < sources.Count(); i++)
                {
                    var file = sources[i];
                    updatelist[i] = new List<tick>();
                    // ---------- Read CSV file ----------
                    var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(file));
                    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        var line = reader.ReadLine();
                        var values = line.Split(',');

                        tick update = new tick();
                        update.disp_name = values[0].ToString();
                        update.trd_date = Convert.ToDateTime(values[1]);
                        update.trdtim_1 = TimeSpan.Parse(values[2]);
                        update.trdprc_1 = Convert.ToDecimal(values[3]);
                        update.trdvol_1 = Convert.ToInt32(values[4]);
                        updatelist[i].Add(update);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(i);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("END LOAD"); // All files are in the memory
                // Aggreagate
                Console.WriteLine("AGGREGATE START");
                int tickAggr = 500;

                for (var w = 0; w < sources.Count(); w++)
                {
                    sourceCandleList[w] = new List<candle>();
                    List<tick> FuturesList = new List<tick>();
                    foreach (var update in updatelist[w])
                    {
                        tick t = new tick();
                        t.disp_name = update.disp_name.ToString();
                        t.trd_date = update.trd_date;
                        t.trdtim_1 = update.trdtim_1;
                        t.trdprc_1 = Convert.ToDecimal(update.trdprc_1);
                        t.trdvol_1 = update.trdvol_1;

                        // Add new tick to the list
                        FuturesList.Add(t);
                        if (FuturesList.Count == Math.Truncate(FuturesList.Count / (decimal)tickAggr) * tickAggr)
                        {
                            candle c = new candle();
                            c.openDate = FuturesList[FuturesList.Count - tickAggr].trd_date;
                            c.openTime = FuturesList[FuturesList.Count - tickAggr].trdtim_1;
                            c.closeDate = FuturesList.Last().trd_date;
                            c.closeTime = FuturesList.Last().trdtim_1;
                            c.open = FuturesList[FuturesList.Count - tickAggr].trdprc_1;
                            c.high = FuturesList.GetRange(FuturesList.Count - tickAggr, tickAggr).Max().trdprc_1;
                            c.low = FuturesList.GetRange(FuturesList.Count - tickAggr, tickAggr).Min().trdprc_1;
                            c.close = FuturesList.Last().trdprc_1;
                            c.volume = FuturesList.GetRange(FuturesList.Count - tickAggr, tickAggr).Sum(tick => tick.trdvol_1);
                            c.totalPrice = (c.open + c.high + c.low + c.close) / 4;
                            sourceCandleList[w].Add(c);
                            if (sourceCandleList[w].Count == 1)
                            {
                                c.id = 0;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                c.id = sourceCandleList[w][sourceCandleList[w].Count - 2].id + 1;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    FuturesList.Clear();
                }
                Console.WriteLine("AGGREGATE END");
                for (var i = 0; i < sources.Count(); i++)
                {
                    updatelist[i].Clear();
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("BUILD PARAMLIST");
            for (int par1 = 8; par1 <= 20; par1 += 4) // parameter deployed
            {
                for (int bollPar = 10; bollPar <= 25; bollPar += 5) // parameter deployed
                {
                    for (int par2 = 6; par2 <= 18; par2 += 4) // parameter deployed
                    {
                        for (int par3 = 14; par3 <= 20; par3 += 3) // parameter deployed
                        {
                            for (int par4 = 10; par4 <= 20; par4 += 5) // parameter deployed
                            {
                                for (int par5 = 4; par5 <= 10; par5 += 2) // parameter deployed
                                {
                                    for (int par6 = 5; par6 <= 30; par6 += 5)
                                    {
                                        for (decimal par7 = 1.0005M; par7 <= 1.002M; par7 += 0.0005M)
                                        {
                                            for (decimal par8 = 1.002M; par8 <= 1.0048M; par8 += 0.0007M)
                                            {
                                                for (decimal par9 = 0.2M; par9 <= 0.5M; par9 += 0.1M)
                                                {
                                                    for (decimal par10 = 0.5M; par10 <= 2; par10 += 0.5M)
                                                    {
                                                        param p = new param();
                                                        p.par1 = par1;
                                                        p.bollPar = bollPar;
                                                        p.par2 = par2;
                                                        p.par3 = par3;
                                                        p.par4 = par4;
                                                        p.par5 = par5;
                                                        p.par6 = par6;
                                                        p.par7 = par7;
                                                        p.par8 = par8;
                                                        p.par9 = par9;
                                                        p.par10 = par10;
                                                        paramList.Add(p);
                                                    }

                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("END BUILD PARAMLIST, scenarios to test:{0}", paramList.Count);
            var sourceCount = sources.Count();
            sources = null;

            Console.WriteLine("Start building pools");
            int maxThreads = 64;
            ConcurrentBag<int> pool = new ConcurrentBag<int>();
            List<candle>[,] CandleList = new List<candle>[maxThreads, sourceCount];
            for (int i = 0; i <= maxThreads - 1; i++)
            {
                pool.Add(i);
                for (int w = 0; w <= sourceCount - 1; w++)
                {
                    CandleList[i, w] = sourceCandleList[w].ConvertAll(p => p);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("End building pools");

            int pItemsProcessed = 0;
            Parallel.ForEach(paramList,
                new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = maxThreads },
                p =>
                {
                    int slot = 1000;
                    while (!pool.TryTake(out slot));

                    var bollPar = p.bollPar;

                    decimal bollingerMiddle = 0;
                    double bBandDeltaX = 0;

                    for (var w = 0; w < sourceCount; w++)
                    {
                        lock (CandleList[slot, w])
                        {
                            for (var ctr = 0; ctr < CandleList[slot, w].Count; ctr++)
                            {
                                CandleList[slot, w][ctr].bollingerUp = 0;  //Bollinger upper line
                                CandleList[slot, w][ctr].bollingerDown = 0;  //Bollinger below line
                                //Bollinger Bands Calculation
                                if (ctr + 1 >= bollPar)
                                {
                                    bollingerMiddle = 0;
                                    bBandDeltaX = 0;
                                    for (int i = 0; i <= bollPar - 1; i++)
                                    {
                                        bollingerMiddle = bollingerMiddle + CandleList[slot, w][ctr - i].totalPrice;
                                    }
                                    bollingerMiddle = bollingerMiddle / bollPar; //average

                                    for (int i = 0; i <= bollPar - 1; i++)
                                    {
                                        bBandDeltaX = bBandDeltaX + (double)Math.Pow(System.Convert.ToDouble(CandleList[slot, w][ctr - i].totalPrice) - System.Convert.ToDouble(bollingerMiddle), 2);
                                    }
                                    bBandDeltaX = bBandDeltaX / bollPar;
                                    decimal bBandDelta = (decimal)Math.Sqrt(System.Convert.ToDouble(bBandDeltaX));
                                    CandleList[slot, w][ctr].bollingerUp = bollingerMiddle + 2 * bBandDelta;
                                    CandleList[slot, w][ctr].bollingerDown = bollingerMiddle - 2 * bBandDelta;
                                    if (CandleList[slot, w][ctr].bollingerUp == CandleList[slot, w][ctr].bollingerDown)
                                    {
                                        Console.WriteLine("?! Items processed=" + pItemsProcessed + " bollPar=" + bollPar + " ctr=" + ctr + " bollingerMiddle=" + bollingerMiddle + " bBandDeltaX=" + bBandDeltaX + " bBandDelta=" + bBandDelta + " bollingerUp=" + CandleList[slot, w][ctr].bollingerUp + " bollingerDown=" + CandleList[slot, w][ctr].bollingerDown);
                                    }
                                }
                                // REMOVED Further calculations happen here
                            }
                            // REMOVED Some evaluations happen here
                        }
                    }
                    // REMOVED Some more evaluations happen here
                    Interlocked.Increment(ref pItemsProcessed);
                    pool.Add(slot);
                });
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var P = new programCLass();
            P.myProgram();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your attempt to write a properly formatted question, however, you are more likely to get a positive response if you post a [mcve].

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I spent 3 hours to trim my code to still produce the error and not be 2000 lines. I did my best here. What do you think about my problem?

Comment: The only way to completely figure out how a multithreaded application is working is by running it. I appreciate that you reposted a more complete piece of code this time but the problem is still too large to handle. This is not a C# problem, this is a multithreaded code problem, your code is tripping over itself. This is usually impossible to see.

Comment: Now having said that we have a bit of an issue here. You have reposted your previous question - [C# equal == seems to be incorrect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37061253/c-sharp-equal-seems-to-be-incorrect) - with this one. Either you close this one and edit your previous one or you close the previous one, a repost is simply out of the question.

Comment: I'm with others on this one - I know what you're dealing w/ here (math/indicators etc.) but it's still very hard to look at it like this, this is a `debugging` problem - but you need to further trim it down to only the very 'minimal viable' example - and you might even figure it out yourself

Comment: To get to the "Minimal" part of a [mcve] you need to start removing code, piece by piece, until you're left with the code that needs to be present to reproduce this problem. Often, along the way, you will figure out the cause of this problem yourself.

Comment: OK, got it. :-( How can I close the previous question?

Comment: To be honest I could only trim the aggregation logic. everything else is already deleted.

Comment: Whether we've been programming for years or we've just started, our brains can only process so much. It's nearly impossible to follow such long methods, even if we're the person who wrote them. The key is to break it up into smaller functions. You'll have a lot of functions, but then you can look at each one and it will be easier to find the bugs. Even if you get it working, what if you need to change something? It will be so confusing that you won't be able to.

Comment: Also, I recommend first getting it working single-threaded. Then if there's a reason to make it multithreaded, do that. Multithreaded apps can be challenging. It will be very hard for you to tell if an error is in the logic or a mistake with the multithreading.